# DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges() Lock

Tags: c#, active-directory, adsi, directoryentry

I'm having an issue concerning a write operation on a Active Directory Server, sometimes (1% of all operations) when i CommitChanges() on a DirectoryEntry i have a lock situation.

I have a dump of my process that has the following output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4MFP.jpg)

This thread is waiting on data to be returned from another server via WinSock.

With this kind of output what is the lock cause?

Another question, what could be my workarround for this situation, could i have a timeout for a CommitChanges operation? I just want to force the process to unlock.

Best Regards,
Mahesh

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Seems like it's just waiting for a reply from your domain controller. Is there a network problem between you and the DC? It will timeout eventually. There is no configurable timeout.

Comment: coonsider there are thousand of user of active directory now we want each user have some group membership  . we connect with our windows services and create thread which add membership for each user. now after some time the service get stuck and does not return the result. we took dump of service and found thread is waiting for AD to return data.   After restart of service everything works perfect